# Is there a better way to have editable elements on a page other than creating a function for each type of edit in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page that provides a table of data, I provide a button to verify the row or delete the row. I also let the user double-click on some of the data to edit it.

When the user finishes editing (by clicking out of the element, or clicking the verify/remove button) it calls a function under my scope that then sends that info to the server which updates the database and returns success or not. At that point I update the modal which updates the elements on the page.

I have a function in my scope for each type of edit. Deleting an entry, verifying it, editing notes, editing a field...etc This makes for a large number of functions.

How can I condense the number of functions I have down and provide a single or just a couple methods for editing data?

Comment: Consider providing a code example.

Comment: Without showing us some code we can't help much.

Comment: I'm not sure what code to use as an example, It's as simple as `function(myParameters){ my behaviors }`, except different behaviors per function depending on what the user edits. There is not exactly much that needs showing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understand well the question.
Make only one function and pass action as arguement. For example:

```
<button ng-click="condensedFunction('delete')"> Delete Row </button>
<button ng-click="condensedFunction('edit')"> Edit Row </button>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.condensedFunction = function(action) {
    if(action === 'delete'){...}
    else if(action === 'edit'){...}
};
```